# Downloading and saving a file fails after publishing app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

When I finish developing app on Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio 2013 and start testing it on my physical device - everything works perfect. 
After publishing app in Windows Mobile Store, when i download app on device, it giving me error in moment i want to download and save file into IsolatedStorage. This occurs in this fragment.

I missing some permissions? Why when I debug app via VS everything is okay, but after publishing - fails?

```
private Task<Stream> DownloadFile(Uri url)
    {
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
        var webClient = new WebClient(); 
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null) task.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else if (e.Cancelled) task.TrySetCanceled();
            else task.TrySetResult(e.Result);
        };
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(url);
        return task.Task;
    }

    private async Task<Problem> DownloadFileFromWeb(Uri uriToDownload, string fileName, CancellationToken cToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = await DownloadFile(uriToDownload))
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (storage.FileExists(fileName)) return Problem.Other;
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile(fileName))
                {
                    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    int bytesread = 0;
                    while ((bytesread = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                    {
                        cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        file.Write(buf, 0, bytesread);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Problem.Ok;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            if (exc is OperationCanceledException)
                return Problem.Cancelled;
            else return Problem.Other;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you requested internet access in the manifest?  What error do you get?

Comment: Thank you my friend, I need to change manifest file.